# Update duplicate values in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, subquery

I have a table which has some duplicate date in certain columns.

For Eg: I have a table with name,email and some more columns of which some rows exist with identical name and email values. I do not want to delete these duplicates as I have other information needed for each row. But there is a third column 'phone' which needs to be updated based on the name and email values. So basically the duplicate rows should have the same phone no.

The standard update query:

```
update table a set a.phone = (select b.phone from table b where b.name = a.name and b.email = a.email);
```

returns the 'Subquery returns more than 1 row error'.

Is there any way possible for me to update the phone column for all my rows(including the duplicates)?

Comment: And how do you determine which of the phone numbers shall be used?

Comment: Obviously, if this is necessary, you likely need to further normalize your data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this query solves your problem. But your subquery has returned more than one row so you can select the top 1 record of the subquery.

```
update table a set a.phone = (select top 1 b.phone from table b where b.name = a.name and b.email = a.email)
```

Comment: subquery calc for every row. If table have many rows then query will be not executed quick. I think `update` with `join` will be beter anyway.

Comment: @OP: The subquery might need an additional filtering criterion like timestamp, because it is currently unknown which value of "phone" you wish to copy.

Comment: @AnirudhR We can use update table `a` with join with table for example `SELECT MIN(phone), name, email FROM b GROUP BY name, email` - now we known wich `phone` matches for pair `name` and `email`.

Answer (score 0):

try this , but it's t-sql . ensure TABLE A has alias name

```
update a set 
a.phone = B.phone
FROM A as a
INNER JOIN
B
ON a.name=B.name AND a.email=B.email
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE a
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT MIN(phone) AS phone, `name`, email FROM b GROUP BY NAME, email) AS t
ON a.name = t.name AND a.email = t.email
SET a.phone = t.phone
```